# Calculating cumulative price on checkbox checked event and changing on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, accumulate

I have a set of check boxes that each and every one is related to a specific row which contains a two drop-downs and a quantity spinner. The first drop-down is for selecting an item and second one for selecting a size of that item based on price. The spinner is for selecting the quantity of the item needed.

I need to count the total price of selected items when a check-box is checked, and on change of the drop-down boxes. Finally, the accumulative price should be displayed in a label for each click.

What I have tried so far is here..

```
function priceCounting(prcField, qtyField) {

    var sum = 0;
    var qty = parseInt(qtyField);
    $(".chkbxPkgCat:checked").each(function(){

        var untPrc = parseFloat(prcField.pop());
        sum = sum+ (qty * untPrc);
        $(".lblAccumPrice1").text(sum);
    });
}
```

On change of check-box, I am calling the function as follows..

```
$(".chkbxPkgCat").change(function(){

    var itm = $(this).parent().parent().next().next().find(".form-control").val();
    var qty = $(this).parent().parent().next().next().next().find(".form-control").text();

    priceCounting(itm,qty);
});
```

Also, this is for item drop down on change event..

```
$("#itemSlct").change(function () {

priceCounting($("#itemSlct option:selected").text(), $("#itmQty").val());
});
```

Same way, I am calling this on-change of spinner and the price dropdown.

But I am not getting the correct accumulative price generated and also I need to deduct the price if it is unchecked a check-box which is checked previously. Anyone can be helpful with this please?

Comment: Could you make snippet and/or post link to fiddle?

Comment: @sinisake It is little harder for me to hard-code all the stuff because I am generating the table dynamically using jquery and populating all the details using database.  If you don't mind I  have added an screenshot of the table. Will this be helpful for you ??

Comment: @sinisake [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjPjZ.png

Comment: I would help you, but I don't understand problem. Images did not help too much...we need produced html...whatever server side language you use, code produces some html output...not sure why you can not simple copy/paste section...